# how to enable cuda only for computing purpose, not for display

Tags: gpgpu

Iam using nvidia gt 440 gpu. It is used for both display and computational  purpose which leads to less performance while computation. can i enable it only for computational purpose? if so how can i disable it from using display.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends -- are you working on Windows or Linux? Do you have any other display adapters (graphics cards) in the machine?

If you're on Linux, you can run without the X Windows Server (i.e., from a terminal) and SSH into the box (or attach your display to another adapter).

If you're on Windows, you need to have a second display adapter. As long as your display is connected to your GeForce 440 GT, there's no way to use it only for computational purposes. That also includes Remote Desktop, which won't work at all unless you have a Tesla card because of the way the WDDM (Windows Display Driver Model) was designed (it can't be accessed from within Session 0, which is where the RDP service runs).

Comment: ,, Iam using ATI card for display purpose and working environment is LINUX(ubuntu), and GeForce 440 GT for ma CUDA purpose. but ma CUDA samples like devicequery cannot run without enabling nvidia using "nvidia-xconfig --enable-all-gpus" . which makes ma CUDA slow and i know this is not the right way. I am really struggling to find a solution for this. thank you

Answer (score 3):

I'm using Intel integrated graphics for display purposes and GPU for compute purpose on Linux. 
You'll need to setup from bios to use the integrated graphics on mobo. This will leave your GPU free. It depends on your hardware available. =)

How much does it affects the performance? I did checked before, the display in windows did takes up some memory (less than 10mb).

Comment: ,, Iam using external ATI card for display. but my CUDA samples are not working . when I enable my nvidia GeForce for display purpose then those CUDA samples are working fine with minimum performance. how can i use Nvidia for CUDA purpose alone. thank you

Comment: your setup should enable nvidia gpu to be use for compute purposes only.

When you mean the samples are not working properly, do you mean it is unable to detect your NVidia GPU? 

First, use deviceQuery sample to check if it is able to detect the NVidia GPU. If it can detect there is no reason why it can't work.

If it can't detect, This is just a guess:
 maybe it's linux OS configuration? How about re-installing the driver to make sure linux detect the NVidia GPU?

Comment: I tried devicequery sample, it was not detecting my Nvidia GPU. when i enable using the comment "nvidia-xconfig --enable-all-gpus", then the devicequery sample works fine and detecting my Nvidia GPU. i cant get into a conclusion why am getting this trouble.

Comment: And i dont think reinstalling will solve this since i have reinstalled many times though.

Answer (score 1):

Check that you have write permission on the /dev/nvidia* devices. The [CUDA C Getting Started Guide for Linux](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/DevZone/docs/html/C/doc/CUDA_C_Getting_Started_Linux.pdf) contains a script that automatically sets the correct permissions at startup.