# Installing the nvidia driver on ubuntu for cuda computation only

Tags: ubuntu, cuda

I am having issues with nvidia graphics driver on ubuntu 14.04. Is there a way to install the driver and use it just for cuda computation not for gui/display purpose? I tried the run installer method described by Robert [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27306724/ubuntu-14-04-how-to-install-cuda-6-5-without-installing-nvidia-driver) with --no-opengl-libs . I trying install cuda 6.5, and I have a nvidia GT 755m on my pc. 
thanks!

Comment: The driver installation is essentially the same whether you want to use it for compute only, or for display only, or for both.  (The only possible difference I can think of might be whether you allow the installer to modify your xorg.conf, for example).  If you want help, I suggest you describe the issues you are having.  And be advised that driver installation questions are considered by some to be off-topic for SO.

Comment: Thanks Robert. I remember I have seen a scipt to disable loading of the nvidia driver at boot. I cannot find that online anymore. I shall try your suggestion.

Comment: @eyebies did you ever solve this?   I'm having the same issue.  This is not the same as an off-topic driver-installation question.  Trying to get the nvidia libraries working for compute purposes only, without interfering with X and with another video card at the same time, is highly non-trivial.  I've been working on it for a week now.  :(

Comment: Nope! I did not get to do it but. People do it. You might want to post on nvidia forum though

Comment: @ bob - Had to put it on a back burner as I got access to another server. But will fix it later.

Comment: @ bob You might find the  following relavant http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12455711/how-to-enable-cuda-only-for-computing-purpose-not-for-display

Answer (score 1):

I had a lot of trouble installing the NVIDIA driver manually on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.  After many false starts in help.ubuntu forums, I learned that the driver now is available through PPA.  I know this isn't quite what you are looking for, but perhaps it will solve the problem.

```
$ sudo apt-get remove nvidia*
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install nvidia-346 nvidia-settings
```